# r what the meaning of the height in the fig created by clprofiles?

Tags: r

Hi I am using kproto to do the clustering
And we can check the result by plotting using clprofiles

But I don't know the meaning of the height of the fig, and I didn't find the meaning in the help document, is there anyone knows it?

I am using the example code as mine.

```
 # generate toy data with factors and numerics
library(clustMixType)
n   <- 100
prb <- 0.9
muk <- 1.5 
clusid <- rep(1:4, each = n)

x1 <- sample(c("A","B"), 2*n, replace = TRUE, prob = c(prb, 1-prb))
x1 <- c(x1, sample(c("A","B"), 2*n, replace = TRUE, prob = c(1-prb, prb)))
x1 <- as.factor(x1)

x2 <- sample(c("A","B"), 2*n, replace = TRUE, prob = c(prb, 1-prb))
x2 <- c(x2, sample(c("A","B"), 2*n, replace = TRUE, prob = c(1-prb, prb)))
x2 <- as.factor(x2)

x3 <- c(rnorm(n, mean = -muk), rnorm(n, mean = muk), rnorm(n, mean = -muk), rnorm(n, mean = muk))
x4 <- c(rnorm(n, mean = -muk), rnorm(n, mean = muk), rnorm(n, mean = -muk), rnorm(n, mean = muk))

x <- data.frame(x1,x2,x3,x4)

# apply k-prototyps
kpres <- kproto(x, 4)
clprofiles(kpres, x)
```

Comment: If you need help interpreting results from statistical models, you should ask for help at [stats.se] instead. You are likely to get better help there. This is not really a specific programming question that's appropriate for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

The plots of the categorical variables (see plot title, which variable is shown) visualize the following:
On the x-axis you see the variable's factor levels and the y-axis shows the proportional occurrence. The different clusters are shown with the color, unfortunately the legend is missing. This will be added in the future, similar to the boxplots for the numerical variables..